# C++ argv path specifier

Tags: c++, string, path, argv

In the interpreter for my programming languages I have to correctly handle the parts in case the `import` function is called. I then need to check if such a file is in the `/libs` folder (located at the same place as my executeable!) and if it doesn't exist I have to check in the directory of the current script.

- How can I get the exact path to the directory where the executeable is located from argv?
- What is the best way to remove the file from the end of a path, e.g:

  `C:/a/b/c/file.exe` should become `C:/a/b/c/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is no guaranteed way to do that.  You can try looking in `argv[0]` but whether that has the full path or just the name of the binary depends on the platform and how your process was invoked.
2. You can use `strrchr` to find the last slash and replace the character after it with `'\0'`

Code example:

```
// Duplicate the string so as not to trash the original
// You can skip this if you don't mind modifying the original data
// and the originald is writeable (i.e. no literal strings)
char *path = strdup(...);

char *last_slash = strrchr(path, '/');
if (last_slash)
{
#if PRESERVE_LAST_SLASH
    *(last_slash + 1) = '\0';
#else
    *last_slash = '\0';
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A non-portable way on Linux (and maybe other *nix) would be to use readlink on /proc/self/exe if argv[0] doesn't contain the entire path.

Answer (score 1):

If your environment has the equivalent of PWD in the environment, you can just append /$argv[0] to it.

This might give you something you don't expect like /foo1/foo2/../foo3/ but that's ok.  It's a valid path and can be globbed.

Comment: The working directory is usually different from the location of the executable.

Comment: This is incorrect.  PWD is your working directory.  If the program was found via PATH, it's location has nothing to do with the working directory.

Comment: Or if it was found by the first line of an executable file. Or if the program was executed in ANY way besides `./my_prog`. Question states that this is an interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Scan backwards from the end of a string for the first `'/'` character.

Answer (score 0):

Not optimal, but works fine:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    using namespace std;
    char buffer[MAXPATHLEN];
    realpath(argv[0], buffer);
    string fullpath = buffer;
    fullpath = string(fullpath, 0, fullpath.rfind("/"));
    cout << fullpath << endl;
}
```

For relative path I'm using realpath(), which is unix/linux specific. For windows you could use GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAXPATHLEN), and of course the separator isn't the same.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows (non portable) use ::GetModuleFileName() and ::PathRemoveFileSpec():

```
TCHAR sPath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
if(::GetModuleFileName(NULL, sPath, MAX_PATH))
    ::PathRemoveFileSpec(sPath))
// sPath is the executable path if the module is an exe
```